# Determine lower value from a list using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#

I have a list with four double values in it

```
var numbers2 = new List<double>() { 2, 3, 9, 7 };
```

I need to get lower value between the first 2 indexes (2 and 3).
Similarly I need to get lower value between index 3 and 4 (9 and 7)

Is there a way in C sharp to determine this using LINQ?
Once I have the lower value from above list i.e 2 and 7; I need to pass these values in the below loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    dac[i] = SetValue(lowerValue[j]); 
}
```

if `i == 0`, I want `lowerValue[j] = 2`. If `i == 1`, I want `lowerValue[j] = 7`

Comment: If `i = 0`, then you're comparing the values at indexes `0` and `1`. If `i = 1`, you're comparing the values at indexes `2` and `3`. Can you spot the pattern? You're looking at `numbers2[i * 2]` and `numbers2[i * 2 + 1]`. You can find the lower of two values using `Math.Min`, or just using `<`. Can you take it from there?

Comment: I know the pattern. However, i would like to determine lower values using LINQ. I also would like to avoid writing if i=0, lowerValue = index 0

Comment: Linq is a bad fit for this: there's no built-in method to take each pair of elements, so you'd have to write your own. I wasn't suggesting writing "if i = 0, lowerValue = numbers2[0]", I was suggesting writing "lowerValue = Math.Min(numbers2[i * 2], numbers2[i * 2 + 1])"

Comment: Sounds like you want [Take / TakeLast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=net-5.0) or [Skip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=net-5.0) together with [Min](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @canton7 This won't work as lowerValue is double and it will give me error that "cannot convert from double to int"

Comment: @user2027571 Where did the int come from? Is `dac` an array of ints?

Comment: No. i is int and number2 is list of double

Comment: Is the list always 4 items long or can it be more as well?

Comment: Its always 4 items long

Comment: @user2027571 I've no idea how you managed to get that error, but you won't have got it from the code I suggested! See here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/khmRn0

Comment: @canton7 You are correct. I just tested now and it worked. Thanks much.

Comment: @canton7 One Last thing, If I want to throw an error if the difference between numbers2[0] and numbers2[1] >10. Similarly if the if the difference between numbers2[2] and numbers2[3] >10. How can we add such a condition in there?

Comment: @user2027571 Find the difference between your numbers, and if it's greater than 10, throw an exception. Which bit of that are you struggling with?

Comment: @canton7 Ok. Makes sense. I will try

Answer (score 0):

Well as others have pointed out, it doesn't seem like there's any reason to use linq.  But if you absolutely had to find some way to do it, then it's possible.  I'll throw 3 options out, the last one being linq.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
        
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var numbers2 = new List<double>() { 2, 3, 9, 7 };
        
        // you stated it's always 4 values.  There's no reason to use linq. The optimal solution would 
        // be a variation of this (with some constant values instead of magic numbers)..
        
        var first = Math.Min(numbers2[0],numbers2[1]);
        var second = Math.Min(numbers2[2],numbers2[3]);
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Lower values: {first},{second}");
        
        // if it was an arbitry sized list (but always even count) you could use a iterator method
        var listOfLowerValues = ToPairs(numbers2);
        
        var values = string.Join(",", listOfLowerValues.Select(x => x.ToString()));
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Lower values: {values}");
        
        // finally if you absolutely had too, you can make it even more inefficient
        // by using linq.
        
        var indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, numbers2.Count);
        var indexed = numbers2.Zip(indexes, (n,i) => (index: i, num: n));
        var odd = indexed.Where(x => x.index%2 == 0).Select(x => x.num).ToArray();
        var even = indexed.Where(x => x.index%2 > 0).Select(x => x.num).ToArray();
            
        var lower = even.Zip(odd,(v1,v2)=> v1 < v2 ? v1 : v2);
        
        var valuesByLinq = string.Join(",",lower.Select(x => x.ToString()));
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Lower values: {valuesByLinq}");
    }
    
    static IEnumerable<double> ToPairs(IEnumerable<double> source)
    {
        int index = 0;
        double previous = 0;
        foreach(var n in source)
        {
            if(index++%2 > 0)
            {
                yield return (previous < n) ? previous : n;
            }
            else
            {
                previous = n;
            }
        }
    }
}
```